# Creating Custom TF.DataSet image dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/add_dataset
This Link shows how to create custom dataset. I have tried with this, but failed to create my own dataset

I have a folder 'Train' and 4 sub folders in that folder and have to create training data and label.
The code I used

```
cd path/to/my/project/datasets/
tfds new my_dataset  # Create `my_dataset/my_dataset.py` template files
# [...] Manually modify `my_dataset/my_dataset.py` to implement your dataset.
cd my_dataset/
tfds build  # Download and prepare the dataset to `~/tensorflow_datasets/`
```

one folder created by the program  my_dataset/ with three .py pgms
I didn't get the data and label.I don't know where the path of my dataset to specify.

NB: My purpose is to call my dataset using

```
ds = tfds.load('my_dataset')
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

After this code

```
cd path/to/my/project/datasets/
tfds new my_dataset
```

You have to modify the python files generated to include your data. (modify all TODO lines)

Given tutorial is not very clear. One simple example for image_classification could have cleared all the issues. I am also stuck on registering dataset step.

I will notify you here If I find a solution.